# Styling in React using var vs vanilla css

Tags: reactjs

Been looking for a way to style components in React, i was following this: [tutorial link](https://www.kirupa.com/react/styling_in_react.htm) but i keep just getting syntax errors even if im copy/pasting the code, so either ive missed something or there is a better way to do it.
forgot to add the code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

export default class Test extends Component {
  var backgroundStyle = React.createClass({
    render: function() {
        padding: 10,
        margin: 10,
       backgroundColor: "#ffde00",
       color: "#333",
       display: "inline-block",
       fontFamily: "monospace",
        fontSize: "32",
        textAlign: "center"
      };

      return (
        <div style={backgroundStyle}>Hi there</div>
      );
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: How should we know whether you missed something or not if you don't know anything about your code, build environment, etc.

Comment: *we don't know ;)

Comment: im asking if setting it up as a variable is the correct way, i can easily enough set in in the stylesheet and apply a className to the element but from what read thats not the correct way React wants you to use, so apparently a var is but if i do that it wont compile, so is it the correct way but incorrectly formatted? or is it the wrong way?

Comment: my bad forgot to add the code snippet im using.

Comment: Sorry, there are so many things wrong with your code. 1) You cannot have variable declarations inside a class body. 2) You cannot have a `return` statement inside an objet literal. 3) You cannot simply put a list of `padding: 10, margin: 10, ...` inside a function body. 4) `React.createClass` is for creating React components, not "styles". Most of these issues have nothing to do with React, but basic JavaScript. You might want to brush up your JavaScript knowledge by reading a tutorial (e.g. http://eloquentjavascript.net/). Also follow the tutorial more closely (the code is correct there).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issue is in this line:

`var backgroundStyle = React.createClass({`

Reason is simple one, style accept an `object` and `React.CreateClass` returns and `html` part not an `object`, you missed that part in the mentioned link, where they defined the style in a separate `object` instead of as a `react component` and used that inside return. check the link again, Run the below snippet, it will work:

```js
class Test extends React.Component {
 render(){
  var backgroundStyle = {
        padding: 10,
        margin: 10,
        backgroundColor: "#ffde00",
        color: "#333",
        display: "inline-block",
        fontFamily: "monospace",
        fontSize: "32",
        textAlign: "center"
      };
     
      return (
        <div style={backgroundStyle}>Hi there</div>
      );
    }
}


ReactDOM.render(<Test/>, document.getElementById('app'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>


<div id='app'></div>
```

Comment: The issue is not just in that line. The whole code doesn't make sense (unfortunately). See [my comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42397874/styling-in-react-using-var-vs-vanilla-css?noredirect=1#comment71944846_42397874) for all the things that are wrong.

Comment: @FelixKling i doubt you are a man or god, you are awesome dude :) salute for this :)

Comment: thanks easy to understand, this did it for me, fixed all the other pieces as well

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

export default class Test extends Component {
    render() {
      const backgroundStyle = {
        padding: 10,
        margin: 10,
        backgroundColor: "#ffde00",
        color: "#333",
        display: "inline-block",
        fontFamily: "monospace",
        fontSize: "32",
        textAlign: "center"
      };

      return (
        <div style={backgroundStyle}>Hi there</div>
      );
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: The OP might need a little bit more help than just "try this".

Answer (score 0):

You're nesting `React.createClass` ***inside*** a React component `class` definition...

If you're only defining one component (which it seems like you're doing) do one or the other but not both.

In addition you're trying to define a CSS class directly within JavaScript, using CSS syntax (which isn't valid JavaScript) ***inside*** a JavaScript function...

---

Check your comments, Felix outlines the above and more...